# images displaying in a site is not looking responsive

Tags: image, responsive-design

we are using follwing code to display images in  this site:

http://demo1.kidsdial.com/

you can see 4 images below "slideshow" images
but it's not looking responsive.

That means, in mobiles and tabs it's not arranged properly & in smaller screen monitors, it's not displaying properly.

What code changes do I have to do to make it responsive?

Comment: style="max-width: 100%;" (if you are speaking about banner 50% off)

Comment: thanks for reply, i did that.... please minimize the screen and check, it's not displaying properly..... seems it's not responsive....

Comment: I have this http://prntscr.com/6r49mw. Isn't it suitable?

Comment: thanks a lot , can you please this too, what'e the solution for this : http://prntscr.com/6r4b11?

Comment: Its screen from your live host. Try to clean your browser cache / or click ctrl+R / ctrl+F5 / open in another browser

Comment: i tried in diffferent browser with private window, but still the same result.... please mnimize the scren litle bit, not fully and check the site.....

Comment: Please provide your screenshot and draw what do you dislike.

Comment: here : http://prntscr.com/6r4b11 

all 3 images are not in a single row as like in original screen. it's displaying one below one below one,

i need to display all 3 images in one row.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img alt="" src="...topoffers1.jpg" style="max-width: 23%;">
<img alt="" src="...topoffers2.jpg" style="max-width: 50%;">
<img alt="" src="...topoffers3.jpg" style="max-width: 23%;">
```

http://prntscr.com/6r4iaj

http://prntscr.com/6r4igz

http://prntscr.com/6r4ilv

Comment: you are genius, i am sure about it.... , on what basis you gave 23 , 50 , 23 , how to set for all images.....

Comment: You can add just such classes for necessary images and then add styles to these classes.

Comment: but surely i need your help once i upload all images, with in an hour i will upload it,

please help me after some time....

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't quick solution for this. Because you need to change the structure of this block. You can look here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids-responsive.html or here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html or google for 'grid block responsive'

Comment: okay, i will try that, but if you are free, please give me some solution, you can take your time.....